# Invalid expression term '>' in framework 2.0

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

```
Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs = str.Split('&').Select(value => value.Split('=')) .ToDictionary(pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1]);
```

How to execute this code in `framework 2.0`

Comment: Are you using VS2005?

Comment: Note that any VS releases older than VS2010 are now end of life. Such questions would be invalid if you use an end-of-life product.

Comment: Since C# 2 doesn't have LINQ & lambda, you need to use `delegate` tweaks and add custom LINQ functions on your own.

Comment: you have to rewrite your code to use .net 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string,string>  opt = new Dictionary<string,string>();
string[] splitted = str.Split('&');
foreach(string spl in splitted)
{
    string[] pair = spl.Split('=');
    opt.Add(pair[0], pair[1]);
}

Console.Write(opt);
```

Comment: The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) in framework 2.0....?

Comment: updated answer to use `string` instead `var`, as var keyword is not supported by .net 2.0